# How can I underline a single character in the Content of a Button in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, underline

I have a number of buttons in my WPF window and I would like to have certain characters in the button contents underlined.

I have tried using the "_" like "My_Content" to underline the C, however this does not appear until the user hits the Alt key, or has their local settings changed. Using < Underline > within the Content property causes an error when I attempt to underline only part of the content like:

Content="My< Underline >C< /Underline >ontent".

I would prefer to set this in the XAML if possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would have to do this explicitly like so:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock>
            My <Underline>C</Underline>ontent
        </TextBlock>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

This would remove the ability to click the button using Alt+Char though. For that an [AccessText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.accesstext.aspx) element is used. But that doesn't support the markup syntax of TextBlock.

Comment: Fantastic, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the ability to click the button using Alt+Char if you add a binding. In my example I'm using Alt+X to exit(Close) the current window

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public RelayCommand(Action execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute?.Invoke();
    }
}
public partial class Window : Window
{

    public ICommand ExitCommand { get; }
    public Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        ExitCommand = new RelayCommand(ExitApplication);
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ExitCommand, ExecuteExitCommand, CanExecuteExitCommand));

        KeyGesture exitKeyGesture = new KeyGesture(Key.X, ModifierKeys.Alt);
        InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(ExitCommand, exitKeyGesture));

    }
    private void ExecuteExitCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExitApplication();
    }
    private void CanExecuteExitCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }
    private void ExitApplication()
    {
        Close();
    }
    private void exitbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExitApplication();
    }
}
```

Make sure you also initialize using System.Windows.Input;